# How to correct package version name in Azure pipeline and remove build ID

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I made a nugget package for a dotnet standard project via CI/CD azure pipeline.
I used the following yml to define the version.

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Major: '1'
  Minor: '1'
  Patch: $[counter(variables['minor'], 1)]
...
...
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
 displayName: 'Preparing build artifacts'
 inputs:
     command: pack
     publishWebProjects: false
     arguments: ' --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     packagesToPack: '**/Package.csproj'
     versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
     majorVersion: '$(Major)'
     minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
     patchVersion: '$(Patch)'
```

The package builds correctly, and I can publish it via my release pipeline.
The issue is that, the package is build with a version suffix constantly attached to it.
For example:

> Package 1.0.0-CI-20201203-170521

And the suffix changes, since it is derived from the actual time by azure devops.
I want to remove this suffix from my version naming.
I don't need it Since my patch version already increments well, and all my packages would have a unique version even without it.

I tried adding

```
<VersionSuffix>MySuffix</VersionSuffix>
```

in my csproj, but it did not change anything. I tried several methods of naming a package's version,
but nothing worked. Please does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `byEnvVar` to achieve your versioning

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    $packageVersion = '$(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)'
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PackageVersion;]$packageVersion"
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Preparing build artifacts'
  inputs:
     command: pack
     publishWebProjects: false
     arguments: ' --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     packagesToPack: '**/Package.csproj'
     versioningScheme: byEnvVar
     versionEnvVar: 'PACKAGEVERSION'
```

otherwise if you select versioning you are forced to use some predefined formats:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly !!!!! Absolutely awesome. Thankyou